# How can I hide a currency's fraction component if it is zero?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I would like the fraction component to be displayed where it is above zero, but hidden when it it equals zero.  For example:

```
{{123.45| currency:"USD$"}}
```

Should show $123.45, but

```
{{123 | currency:"USD$"}}
```

must show $123, and not $123.00.

http://plnkr.co/edit/k8JEGj8KOon6DqB1oZ18

Comment: Are you saying you want to show decimals when they exist, but no decimals when the decimal part is zero?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're saying you only want the fraction part visible if the fraction part is larger than zero.  If so you can use this;

```
{{amount | currency:"USD$": amount % 1 > 0 ? 2 : 0}}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/2MHHYspvtYd0pdd1eF49?p=preview

Comment: it is correct but everytime i use currency filter i have to write a logic. Even if i create customFilter to do it. I am looking for much useful and elegant way

Comment: How about writing a custom filter that has the above logic, so then you can use `{{ amount | myCurrency:"USD$" }}`?

Answer (score 1):

based on @Stafford Williams answer, i created a custom directive.

also, i adjusted it to support the case that you don't provide a symbol.

```
.filter('currencyWithoutZeros', ['$filter', function($filter) {
        return function() {
            // Clone arguments so we can modify it
            var argsCopy = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

            var currencyFilter = $filter("currency"); 

            // If currency symbol was not provided, we need to manually add a second argument
            if (argsCopy.length == 1)
              argsCopy.push(undefined);

            var input = argsCopy[0]; 
            argsCopy.push(input % 1 > 0 ? 2 : 0);

            return currencyFilter.apply(undefined, argsCopy);
        };
    }]);
```

to use it:

```
  fractions only if existing with custom directive: <span id="currency-no-fractions-custom">{{amount | currencyWithoutZeros:"USD$" }}</span><br/>
  fractions only if existing with custom directive (without symbol): <span id="currency-no-fractions-custom-no-symbol">{{amount | currencyWithoutZeros }}</span>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/7ais8OLGOAAcTMfRHoMf?p=preview